# Compact Riemann manifolds with constant injectivity radius

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm interested in compact Riemann manifolds which have that property that the injectivity radius at a point $p$ doesn't depend on $p$. Another way to put this is that the function $$p \mapsto d(p, \text{Cut}(p))$$ is constant. Here, $\text{Cut}(p)$ denotes the cut locus of the point $p$. Are there any results concerning manifolds with this property?

Comment: Besides homogeneous manifolds,  do you now examples ?

Comment: No I don't, I'm afraid. It's a necessary condition that came up while studying a problem. I know that homogeneous manifolds have this property but to what extent does it characterize them?

Comment: I'd be truly happy to see the definition of the $Cut(p)$.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic starting at $p$ and let $B=$sup$\{b>0 : \gamma_{[0, b]}$ is minimizing$\}$. If $B< \infty$, we call $q=\gamma(B)$ the cut point of $p$ along $\gamma$. The cut locus of $p$ is the set of all points $q$ such that $q$ is the cut point of $p$ along some geodesic.

Comment: Is $\ d(p, Cut(p)) = \sup \ldots\ $ or $\ \ldots =\ldots\inf\ldots\,$?

Comment: A trivial way to construct an example that is not homogeneous is to take a product with a small circle.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński It's an infimum.

Comment: @DouglasZare Nice observation. That means a torus of revolution is such an example.

Answer (score 7):

An example of an inhomogeneous manifold with injectivity radius the same for all points can be constructed as follows.

Recall that a point of the cut locus is either in the conjugate locus or there is more than one minimizing geodesic connecting to it.  For the round metric of constant curvature $+1$ on the real projective plane, all the points of the cut locus are at distance $\frac{\pi}{2}$ whereas to reach the conjugate locus you have to travel the distance $\pi$.  Therefore for small perturbations of the metric, all points of the cut locus are of the second variety (*not* in the conjugate locus).

Now take a small rotationally-symmetric and centrally-symmetric perturbation of the metric on the unit sphere which "flattens" it a bit at the poles. Then the shortest closed geodesics are precisely the ones passing through the poles.  The common length of those geodesics is $4$ times the distance to the injectivity radius at every point of the quotient metric on the real projective plane.

Comment: But what can we say about manifolds with this property?

Comment: Yes, they exist :-)

Comment: So the condition doesn't characterize homogeneous manifolds. Does it imply anything?

Comment: If you feel like getting into hard-core Riemannian geometry, you could try to investigate the relation of this condition for metrics on $RP^2$ to the property that the filling radius is exactly one-third of the diameter.

Comment: I'll take a look at your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, there's a simpler example. The torus of revolution in $\Bbb{R}^3$ has the property that $\text{inj}_p$ is the same for all points $p$.

Comment: If it is thin enough.

Comment: Yes, if it's thin enough.